# I want to send some parameter with some live url in Angular 8

Tags: routes, angular-routing, angular8, url-parameters

I want to send some parameter with some live url like [Link](https://google.co.in?Id:1234&carId:127**%20in%20**Angular%208). How can i send these parameter with url.

```
buyPolicy() {

        let obj = {
            Id: this.idNumber,
            Dob: this.dob,
            SerialNo: this.vehicleSeqNo,
            MobileNo: this.mobile,
            EmailId: this.email,
            RefID: this.vehicleId
        };

        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: { ...obj }
        };

        this.router.navigate(['https://google.co.in'], navigationExtras);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had tried, as this code, and this is work for me

```
let obj = {
            Id: this.idNumber,
            Dob: this.dob,
            SerialNo: this.vehicleSeqNo,
            MobileNo: this.mobile,
            EmailId: this.email,
            RefID: this.vehicleId
        };
        let windowParams = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,
width=0,height=0,left=-1000,top=-1000`;
        var url = 'https://google.co.in/Default.aspx' + "?" + "Id=" + obj.Id + "&Dob=" + obj.Dob + "&SerialNo=" + obj.SerialNo + "&MobileNo=" + obj.MobileNo + "&EmailId=" + obj.EmailId + "&RefID=" + obj.RefID;

        window.open(url, windowParams);
```

but in this case it open a new tab in same window , but i want to open in new popup window . my **windowParams** is not working for me.